# SDL Multiple Key Press Issue

Tags: c++, events, sdl

I came across an issue with SDL - having both w a s d and arrow keys simultaneously pressed - there's some kind of incompatibility whilst holding down s, d and left and down as well as w d and up and left keys. If i tend to use the combinations mentioned above, only 3 keys seem to work, otherwise, any other combination with more than 3 keys works rather well. Code below: 
Event checking ( in class CEvent, calling child's functions )

```
switch(Event->type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN: {//KEYBOARD_KEYDOWN
        onKeyDown(Event->key.keysym.sym,Event->key.keysym.mod,Event->key.keysym.unicode);
        break;

    }

    case SDL_KEYUP: {//KEYBOARD_KEYUP
        onKeyUp(Event->key.keysym.sym,Event->key.keysym.mod,Event->key.keysym.unicode);
        break;
    }
}
```

This calls two functions, overridden from parent class ( in class Core, child of CEvent ):

```
void Core::onKeyDown(SDLKey sym, SDLMod mod, Uint16 unicode) {
    switch(sym) {
      //pl1
        case SDLK_UP: pl1.pmu = true; break;
        case SDLK_RIGHT: pl1.pmr = true; break;
        case SDLK_DOWN: pl1.pmd = true; break;
        case SDLK_LEFT: pl1.pml = true; break;
      //pl2
        case 'w': pl2.pmu = true; break;
        case 'd': pl2.pmr = true; break;
        case 's': pl2.pmd = true; break;
        case 'a': pl2.pml = true; break;
      case SDLK_ESCAPE: onExit(); break;
  }
}

void Core::onKeyUp(SDLKey sym, SDLMod mod, Uint16 unicode) {
  switch(sym) {
    //pl1
    case SDLK_UP: pl1.pmu = false; break;
    case SDLK_RIGHT: pl1.pmd = false; break;
    case SDLK_DOWN: pl1.pml = false; break;
    case SDLK_LEFT: pl1.pmr = false; break;
    //pl2
    case 'w': pl2.pmu = false; break;
    case 'd': pl2.pmr = false; break;
    case 's': pl2.pmd = false; break;
    case 'a': pl2.pml = false; break;
  }
}
```

Here's how this is called( in class Core, child of CEvent ):

```
while( Running ) {
  FPS_START = SDL_GetTicks();
  while( SDL_PollEvent( &Eventhn ) ) {
    onEvent( &Eventhn );
  }
  onLoop();
  onRender();
  regulateFPS();
}
onCleanup();
```

I just can't figure what causes this as the program loops through this until there are no events remaining in the buffer.

Comment: I have seen evidence that different keyboards behave differently with same software. How many keyboard keys can be simultaneously pressed is therefore keyboard-specific problem. Ask FPS gamers, they know what is good keyboard and what is not.

Comment: It's a hardware thing. Normal keyboards suffer from this. There are special gamer keyboards to overcome this issue.

Comment: @ivaylo9603, It's just as others said, that's key-ghosting; there's nothing you can to do fix it, since it's  a hardware limitation. 

Some of the "standard" keyboards, so to speak, will cut down input after 3+ keys pressed simultaneously (from my own experience).

To the others that mentioned the gaming keyboards - they're by no means the panacea. They're still limited. I haven't tested thoroughly (I own a gaming keyboard), but I don't think that even they will pick-up eight pressed keys simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, though, I'm a laptop user :/. Anyways it is not essential to me, thought the problem might be in my code. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with SHIFT + SPACE + DOWN. I do not treat the DOWN key differently from the UP key, yet the latter works in this particular key combo. If I first press DOWN, and only then the other two, it works. So it is related to what kind of keys you press, and in what order. Using SDL2 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be the key blocking phenomenon described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_blocking_and_ghosting

There's nothing you can do about this. If you change keyboard, you may get lucky and find one that has problems with a different combination of keys (hopefully one that you're not using).

Comment: So it's not a software issue. I'm a laptop user myself, there goes my luck. Well, atleast I know I can't do anything about it, hoping consumers would be more fortunate. Thank you :)

Comment: @ivaylo9603: well, key ghosting is one of the reasons key assignments should always be configurable in PC games.